# Heroku Ruby on Rails App failing after recent push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, github, push

I tried to push an update to my heroku app from github. I added some text and updated my gem file as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "1.9.3"
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'jquery-rails' [...]
```

However my logs are showing

> *"DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in
>   vendor/plugins! Support for these plugs will be removed in Rails
>   4.0"*

I know Rails 4.0 was released late June... could this be causing my issue?

Before that I see the following error lines:

> *"/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.2/lib/ruby1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in
>   'select'
>  [2013-08-08 05:04:37] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM"*

which is the first time I see an error in my logs. Does anyone know if either of these are the issue?

Thanks so much!

Comment: The deprecation warning is just that: a warning. Fix it, but it's not causing your issue. And from your log file it doesn't seem like your app is "failing": when you push new code to Heroku, it restarts the dynos. Your running processes get a SIGTERM, with causes them to exit, and print the log you quote above. I suppose that right after that you see a new process spinning up, correct? Expect such "SIGTERM" messages every time you deploy to Heroku, unless you install a handler for it and handle it yourself.

Comment: @NitzanShaked you should turn that into an answer.

Comment: First of all he could not fix deprecation warning because it's caused by HEROKU. Can only ignore it. Second - please include full log.]

Answer (score 0):

The deprecation warning is just that: a warning. Fix it, but it's not causing your issue.

And from your log file it doesn't seem like your app is "failing": when you push new code to Heroku it restarts the dynos. Your running processes get a `SIGTERM`, with causes them to exit, and print the log you quote above. I suppose that right after that you see a new process spinning up, correct?

Expect such `SIGTERM` messages every time you deploy to Heroku, unless you install a handler for it and handle it yourself.